# jQuery: disabling prop IF checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, checked, prop

I have some script that I have written and it works exactly how I would like it too, but it seems pretty lengthy for what it does: http://jsfiddle.net/x6xbymmL/

```
$(".class2").prop("disabled", true);
$(".class3").prop("disabled", true);

$('input[class^="class"]').click(function() {
var $this = $(this);

if ($this.is(".class1")) {
    if ($(".class1:checked").length > 0) {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class2").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".class2").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}

if ($this.is(".class2")) {
    if ($(".class2:checked").length > 0) {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class2").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class2").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", false);
    }
}

if ($this.is(".class2")) {
    if ($(".class2:checked").length > 1) {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class2").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class2").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}

if ($this.is(".class3")) {
    if ($(".class3:checked").length > 0) {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class2").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class2").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

});

I am trying to figure out if I have written it the best I can or if there is a better way? Also a nicety would be to disable all others in group except the checked one so that the user can go back if they have  checked the wrong option... I really struggled getting this to work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a significantly shorter version of your code that has the exact same functionality.  See it work here:  http://jsfiddle.net/x6xbymmL/1/

```
$(".class2, .class3").prop("disabled", true);
$('input[class^="class"]').click(function () {
    if ($(".class1:checked").length > 0) {
        $(".class1").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".class2, .class3").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    if ($(".class2:checked").length > 0 || $(".class3:checked").length === 1) {
        $(".class3").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    if ($(".class3:checked").length === 1 || $(".class2:checked").length === 2) {
        $(".class3, .class2").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

You really had way too many if statements in there for what you were trying to accomplish.  It was working, and you were being thorough, but most of it was unnecessary.

Comment: That is a lot shorter, thank you very much for your time, works perfectly :)

Comment: No problem, let me know if there's anything else I can help with :)

Comment: The only thing I am trying to figure now is how to let the user 'go back' if they click the wrong checkbox

Comment: Since your original code didn't have that functionality and we try to keep the answers related to the original question, I would recommend posting a new question and I'll take a look at it.  It's definitely possible.

Comment: I think its still messy. Would you like to elaborate on the logic aka what is happening. Because i have a feeling that you could work it    shorter by toggling classes on the html elements rather that doing all those checks about the states the elements are.

Comment: First group you could simply use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes so only one radiobutton is checked at given moment. About second group you could reset checked if user selects a third one so you dont have to disable them and the use can always select max 2 or the large. If my approach sounds good i could give an example code but will do it tommorow